# Square Triangle numbers and Pell's equation

Tags: number-theory, square-numbers, pell-type-equations

So i have just started to study number theory and i was asked this question.

Now i tried to search online and i found out pell equation can used to solve this question. Now in an online video i saw that $$x^2-2y^2=1$$ is the equation and you take the solution point such as the first solution $x_1=3$ and $y_1=2$ and you input that into $T_n=S_n$ and solving that you will get your first triangular square number.

> My question is how do you go about finding the solutions to pell equation without doing trial by error.

Please correct me if i am wrong or got some misinformation

---

The first two numbers that are both squares and triangles are $1$ and $36$.

- Find the next one and, if possible, the one after that.
- Can you figure out an efficient way to find triangular-square numbers?
- Do you think that there are infinitely many?

Comment: Have you researched Pell's equation? The Wikipedia article on the subject, along with articles of Keith Conrad, should give you a fairly complete picture. You have to find or look up the fundamental solution, from which all other (infinitely many) solutions may be generated.

Comment: Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76040/general-formula-to-obtain-triangular-square-numbers)

Comment: Once you get the Pell equation as shown in some answers, you can use this method to solve it.
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3099910/how-does-this-elementary-method-of-solving-pells-equation-compare-with-the-clas

Answer (score 4):

I don't understand how you got the equation $x^2+2y^2=1$ for finding square triangle numbers

We have the diophantine equation, $T_n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}=k^2$.

$\begin{align*}
   n^2 + n
     &= 2 k^2 \\
   4 n^2 + 4 n
     &= 8 k^2 \\
   (2 n + 1)^2
     &= 8 k^2 + 1
\end{align*}$

Make the substitution $u =2 n + 1$ to get
$u^2 - 8 k^2 = 1$.

A trivial solution to this is $(3,1)$
The rest of the solutions can be found in the form $(u, k)$, where $u_i + 2 \sqrt{2} k_i = (3 + 2 \sqrt{2})^i$ for natural number, $i$. This gives solutions to $u_i$ as $\frac{(3+2\sqrt{2})^i+(3-2\sqrt{2})^i}{2}$.

For example, $u_2=\frac{9+12\sqrt{2}+8+9-12\sqrt{2}+8}{2}=17$. This gives $n=8$ and $T_8=36$.

I don't really like this form, because it gets harder to deal with when you are dealing with larger powers. You can instead use the fact that the expression for $u_i$ is similar to the explicit formula of a recursion with characteristic polynomial, $x^2-6x+1$.

This gives the recursion $u_i=6u_{i-1}-u_{i-2}$ with initial conditions of $u_1=3$ and $u_2=17$. We can make the substitution $u_i=2n_i+1$, so $n_i=6n_{i-1}-n_{i-2}+2$, where $n_1=1$ and $n_2=8$.

Answer (score 1):

There are infinite of them, see the sequence [A001110 on OEIS](https://oeis.org/A001110).

$$0, 1, 36, 1225, 41616, 1413721, 48024900, \dots$$

Without going on much detail about continued fractions and Pell equations, we have the formula (yanked from OEIS):

$$a(n) = \frac {(17+12\sqrt 2)^n+(17-12\sqrt2)^n-2}{32}$$

Answer (score 1):

$T_n=\dfrac{n(n+1)}2=m^2\iff(2n+1)^2-2(2m)^2=1$

There are infinitely many solutions to the Pell equation $x^2-2y^2=1$,

given by $y=$[$\;0,2,12,70,408,...$](http://oeis.org/A001542) (click on numbers for more information;

$ y_n=6y_{n-1}-y_{n-2}$), so square triangular numbers are squares of $0,1,6,35,204,...$

Answer (score 0):

Pell's equation is $$x^2-Dy^2=1$$

Now, if you meant $$x^2-2y^2=1$$

The solutions arise when you find a period in the continued fraction for $\sqrt{2}$. For this, consider
\begin{align}
\sqrt{2} &= 1+(\sqrt{2}-1) \\
\implies \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}-1} &= \sqrt{2}+1
\end{align}
And then solution follows.