# Is it possible to define an implicit function for the Kth N such that N(N+1)/2 is a perfect square?

Tags: diophantine-equations, square-numbers, derivation-of-formulae

The questions asks:

Define a formula to yield the Kth N for which there exists an integer X less than or equal to N for which the sum of the integers from 0 to X (inclusive) is equal to the sum of the integers from X to N (inclusive).
Through a bit of algebra, we can paraphrase the question as:
Find the Kth N for which N(N+1)/2 equal to some perfect square.

I have defined a recursive formula for this:

f(1) = 1

f(2) = 8

f(3) = 49

f(k) = 4f(k-2)(f(k-2) + 1) for k > 3

So the numbers are: 1,8,49,288,9800...

My question is if it is possible to find an "implicit" function for yielding N.

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3821142/square-triangle-numbers-and-pells-equation) about triangular-square numbers

Comment: What about $1681?\;$  Cf. [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A001108)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_triangular_number

Comment: Did you want an *explicit* function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the title question is $f(k)=\dfrac{(3-2\sqrt2)^k+(3+2\sqrt2)^k-2}4$.

For further information, see [this related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3821142/square-triangle-numbers-and-pells-equation).

This sequence is in [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A001108) and includes $1681,$ which your formula doesn't have.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I needed an implicit formula only. I understand there was some flaw in my reasoning which caused it to jump over numbers such as 1681.